# Django Query Decimal type Issue

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, filter

I'm filtering objects using filter query. Retrieving data from mongodb where data is stored as type "int32".

While filtering objects using following command:

```
query_product = Product.objects.filter(unit_price__lt=30)
```

it is throwing an error:

[image: Decimal.decimal is not comparing unit_price attribute is of type int32]

I know this is causing my error because using filter when I query string elements it is working fine.

I'm new to django. Please help how to avoid this error.

I have tried python int function to convert 30 to int but I think django is still processing it as decimal.

Datatype of unit_price at database side.
[unit_price datatype Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHWlk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to post a comment and you didn't post your Product model, but from what you're saying, it seems that your field *unit_price* is defined as decimal in your Product model and your database is configured as int. If that's the case, I can think of just one possibility: you defined this field as int first, changed to decimal later and did not run migrations.

To fix this, you need to run these commands in your virtual environment, so the field in the database will be updated to a decimal type, and you can filter normally:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I that's not the case, please, post your Product model and your view to help to identify the problem.

**Edit (based on the information you provided in the comments):**

To convert int to decimal, you can do this:

```
from decimal import Decimal

my_int_var = 50
my_int_converted = Decimal(my_int_var)
```

But i really think that converting data this way can cause you problems in the future, so the best course of action would be normalize both types. Assuming that you want this field to be a decimal type, you can change something in the model, like the *max_digits* variable and run migrations again. This way the column would be set again to decimal in the database. If you get errors when doing this, you can try to delete the data in the table and then run migrations.

After that, if your data is in json format, you can load the data again [using the loaddata command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#provide-data-with-fixtures) in your venv.

Comment: yes in product model i have defined this field as:
unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2).
And at time of migrations it is passed as a decimal field. but at my database i pushed JSON data which contains unit_price as int32.

I have attached picture in my question above you can see datatype

Comment: im passing json data to mongodb which than creates collections. how do i pass unit_price value there with type decimal not int.

Comment: IMPORTANT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I can read product all fields including unit_price but type of unit_price is int. The issue arises because i think filter function when performing operation pass argument value as type decimal. Can i enforce django to pass it is int so that they can be compared

Comment: The filter will be applied in the same type defined in your model, in this case, decimal, so I think the error is related to this. In the image, its shown that the database is still set as int. After you defined the field type as decimal and run migrations, your database type should be updated as well. I'm not familiar with mongodb (I use postgres), but I think the process is the same for both. Have you tried to run the commands again after the change? As a side note, you don't need to convert values in this case, just to normalize the field in your code with your database.

Comment: i run my migrations initially with decimal field. There was no data in my database at that time only empty table. I than directly insert data in my database using Datagrip. The data has unit_price values as type int. But as i told you when table was empty datatype of unit_price was decimal. So what i think is that upon insertion coloum datatype is changed to what your type of data you are inserting. Similarly when i have unit_price as type of string. Database unit_price was changed to string.
i must convert my data to decimal as last solution.But i dont know How to do it -_-. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer based on the information you provided. I don't know Datagrip, but it seems odd to me that it changes the data type in your database, so i also provided a Django alternative to load the data. Hope it helps.